# mysql Error code 1064 when trying to insert id from one table as foreign key in second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a stored procedure that adds an instructor in a department.
The problem is that I cannot manage to select the instructor id from one table based on the first and last name from the input and insert it in the second table as the foreign key.

This is the error that i receive:

```
Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL 
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server 
version for the right syntax to use near 'instructor.id WHERE
research_dep.name = researchName and instructor.firstname = 
' at line 4
```

This is how I am trying to make the procedure

```
DELIMITER @@
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_add_instructor_to_research
(iFirstName varchar(60)
 , iLastName varchar(60)
 , researchName varchar(60))   
BEGIN

INSERT INTO research_dep.fk_instructor_id 
SELECT id 
FROM instructor 
WHERE instructor.firstname = iFirstName 
and instructor.lastname = iLastName 
and research_dep.name = researchName;

END @@
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I don't see an `and instructor.firstname = ` after `research_dep.name = researchName` in your query.  Is this the query you used?

Comment: The query in the question and the error message do not match. In the error message `instructor.id` is in front of the `where` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided any details of the tables you are manipulating - usually a good idea. However in this case its not really relevant.

```
and research_dep.name = researchName;
```

You can't reference the table you are inserting INTO (research_dep) from a query which doesn't use it as a data source (in the from list). Even if you did have the table in the from list, you would need to assign it a different alias and add a join clause.

Further, you can't INSERT INTO a field - you insert into a table (with an optional field list in brackets). e.g.

```
INSERT INTO research_dep (fk_instructor_id)
```

I can't tell from the code you have provided what you intend the query to do and hence cannot suggest what the query should be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sepecify column name in the insert statement, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN1) SELECT COLUMN2 FROM TABLE2;
```

Your query will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO research_dep (instructor_id) 
SELECT id 
FROM instructor 
WHERE instructor.firstname = iFirstName 
and instructor.lastname = iLastName 
and research_dep.name = researchName;
```